# Should i have root rights in a fresh installed Gingerbread Emulator?

Tags: android, emulation, root

I'm wondering why i have Root rights in a fresh installed Emulator with API Level 10 (Gingerbread). I downloaded the API and created a new Emulator Device. The i used `adb shell` to get a shell and typed in `su`, also i can access all folders that have only permissions for root and system.

I always thought i needed to have to run a root exploit in order to get root rights on a emulator device...

Maybe its because I'm using the Android Reverse VM? But i downloaded the android-10 platfrom new and fresh...

Comment: I think users have root rights even on older emulators. Atleast I have root rights on all emulators 2.1 onwards!

Comment: that bad because i need to test what happens if i have no root...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android Kernel can be build in 3 ways: user, userdebug and engineering. The Emulator Kernel seems to be a engineering Kernel, since thats mostly what i want to do with the Emu.

If you need no root you have to build your own kernel with the user options to have a productive environment same as the kernel on a smartphone.